# Spring Boot Hibernate Can't Delete verification token

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Using spring boot, Java and hibernate.

Put simply, I can verify a user, send a verification email and when the user follows the link they are emailed. It takes them to a verification page. At that page they are redirected depending on whether they are signed in or not and if they are verified previously or not.

Each instance, the token should be deleted. I do not know what I am doing wrong in the code.

This is the VerifyController

```
import com.blah.app.models.Alert;
import com.blah.app.models.AlertType;
import com.blah.app.models.entities.User;
import com.blah.app.models.entities.VerificationToken;
import com.blah.app.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.blah.app.repositories.VerificationTokenRepository;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Controller
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/user-verification")
public class VerificationController {

  private final MessageSource messageSource;
  private final HttpServletRequest request;
  private final VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepository;
  private final UserRepository userRepository;


  @GetMapping
  public String verificationRedirect(@RequestParam("token") String token,
                                     RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
UUID uuidToken = UUID.fromString(new String(decoder.decode(token)));


Optional<VerificationToken> optionalVerificationToken =
    this.verificationTokenRepository.findByToken(uuidToken);

if (optionalVerificationToken.isPresent()) {
  VerificationToken verificationToken = optionalVerificationToken.get();
  User user = verificationToken.getUser();


  if (user.isEnabled() == true) {
    //user enabled

    if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
    //user signed in and enable
      this.verificationTokenRepository.delete(verificationToken);

      Alert alert = Alert.builder()
          .type(AlertType.WARNING)
          .message(this.messageSource
              .getMessage("messages.verifiedAlready", null, 
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()))
          .closable(true)
          .build();
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alerts", Collections.singletonList(alert));
      this.verificationTokenRepository.delete(verificationToken);

      return "redirect:app";
    } else {
      //user signed out and enabled
      this.verificationTokenRepository.delete(verificationToken);

      Alert alert = Alert.builder()
          .type(AlertType.WARNING)
          .message(this.messageSource
              .getMessage("messages.verifiedAlreadySignedOut", null,
                  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()))
          .closable(true)
          .build();

      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alerts", Collections.singletonList(alert));

      return "redirect:sign-in";
    }

  } else {
    //user not enabled


    if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
      //user is signed in
  //        FIXME: needs to redirect to app
      user.setEnabled(true);
      this.verificationTokenRepository.delete(verificationToken);


      Alert alert = Alert.builder()
          .type(AlertType.SUCCESS)
          .message(this.messageSource
              .getMessage("messages.verificationSuccess", null,
                  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()))
          .closable(true)
          .build();

      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alerts", Collections.singletonList(alert));

      return "redirect:app";
    } else {
      //uesr not signed in
      user.setEnabled(true);
      this.verificationTokenRepository.delete(verificationToken);
      Alert alert = Alert.builder()
          .type(AlertType.SUCCESS)
          .message(this.messageSource
              .getMessage("messages.verificationSuccessSignedOut", null,
                  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()))
          .closable(true)
          .build();
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alerts", Collections.singletonList(alert));

      return "redirect:sign-in";
    }


  }
  }
  Alert alert = Alert.builder()
    .type(AlertType.WARNING)
    .message(this.messageSource
        .getMessage("messages.verifiedInvalidToken", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()))
    .closable(true)
    .build();

redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alerts", Collections.singletonList(alert));

return "redirect:sign-in";
   }
}


User entity



import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user_account")
 public class User extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
  private String forename;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
  private String surname;

  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text", unique=true)
  private String email;

  @Transient
  private String password;

  @Transient
  private String confirmPassword;

  @Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
  private String passwordHash;

  @Column(name = "enabled")
  private boolean enabled;

  public User() {
    super();
    this.enabled=false;
  }

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<UserRole> roles;

  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
  private VerificationToken verificationToken;

};
```

verifification token entity

```
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Entity
@Setter
@Table(name = "user_verification_token")
public class VerificationToken extends BaseEntity  {

  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private UUID token;

  @OneToOne(optional = false)
  private User user;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing he cascade completely, initially i added the cascade to the verification token like so..

```
 @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
  private User user;
```

This of course meant that deleting the token deleted the user. When i removed the cascade it allowed for the token to be deleted without removing the user.

```
  @OneToOne(optional = false)
      private User user;


 @OneToOne( mappedBy="user")
  private VerificationToken verificationToken;
```